# Swift Type Inference and Protocols with Associated Types

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, swift-protocols

**EDIT**: I can't understand why in the where clause below - `where U.CacheType == T` in AnyCacheable class Swift doesn't treat that statement as a constraint but simply sets T to `U.CacheType`. Type inference is the worst when things aren't readily apparent :-)

---

I am trying to follow Swift's Type erasure discussed [here](https://medium.com/@NilStack/swift-world-type-erasure-5b720bc0318a) -

Specifically the code below:

```
protocol Cacheable {
    associatedtype CacheType
    func decode(_ data:Data) ->CacheType?
    func encode()->Data?

}

extension String:Cacheable {
    func decode(_ data:Data)->String? {
        let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        return string
    }
    func encode()->Data? {
        return data(using: .utf8)
    }
}

class AnyCacheable<T>:Cacheable {
    private let _encode:()->Data?
    private let _decode:(_ data:Data)->T?

    init<U:Cacheable>(_ cacheable:U) where U.CacheType == T {
        self._encode = cacheable.encode
        self._decode = cacheable.decode
    }

    func decode(_ data:Data)->T? {
        return _decode(data)
    }

    func encode() -> Data? {
        return _encode()
    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine if I create a new instance of `AnyCacheable` as -

```
let cacheable:AnyCacheable = AnyCacheable("Swift")
```

I don't need to explicitly specify the concrete type of 'T' like `let cacheable:AnyCacheable = AnyCacheable<String>("Swift")`

How does Swift infer the concrete type for 'T'? From the initializer -

```
init<U:Cacheable>(_ cacheable:U) where U.CacheType == T {
    self._encode = cacheable.encode
    self._decode = cacheable.decode
}
```

I can see that Swift can infer the type for 'U' from the initializer argument (in this case a String type). In the where clause 'T' is on rhs. So how does that expression evaluate to true?

Answer (score 0):

String is a Cacheable and its `decode` returns a String, so its associated type CacheType must be String.

AnyCacheable is initialized with a String, which is a Cacheable as required; so its U is String. But `U.CacheType` is T. So T is String.

---

To see that this is so, change the definition of String's adoption of Cacheable to this:

```
extension String:Cacheable {
    func decode(_ data:Data)->Int? {
        return 42
    }
    func encode()->Data? {
        return data(using: .utf8)
    }
}
```

Now compile your code and look to see what type you get in the line

```
let cacheable:AnyCacheable = AnyCacheable("Swift")
```

It is `AnyCacheable<Int>`.

Comment: This is the part I didn't understand - "But U.CacheType is T. So T is String." Isn't U.CacheType == T a comparison expression that returns a Bool? In other words we aren't _setting_ 'T' to 'U.CacheType' but have a provided a evaluation check to _ensure_ that 'U.CacheType' is the same as 'T'. Moreover U.CacheType is on lhs of that evaluation so how is 'T' set to 'U.CacheType'?

Comment: Yes, it's not quite the use of "where" that you might expect. But if you reversed the _order_, `where T == U.CacheType`, you'd get the same result (it's commutative), and it's an _equality_, not a constraint (not a colon).

Comment: Perhaps a way to think of it is that `where T == U.CacheType` (which, as I just said, is an equivalent expression) can mean "T is _another name for_ whatever `U.CacheType` turns out to be".

Comment: But from everything I read the _where_ clause does indeed specify constraints that the generic type parameters must conform to. Here is an excerpt from Apple’s Swift manual - “You can also specify the requirement that two types be identical, using the == operator. For example, <S1: Sequence, S2: Sequence> where S1.Iterator.Element == S2.Iterator.Element expresses the constraints that S1 and S2 conform to the Sequence protocol and that the elements of both sequences must be of the same type.” So back to square 1. The runtime can easily infer that U is a String. How does T become a String?